# Sending event data to google analytics?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have a requirement where I need to send which all elements on page user has used 
for e.g. user abc on page www.xyz.com/report has selected ddlCities.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-76384817-1', 'none');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
```

and then I send the data like this
`ga('send', 'event', pathName, val.id);`
 });

I get the data under Events when User is online but not after he is not active on the website.

Is this the only way to send event data?.....Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? From what I'm reading, you are trying to send event data for a particular user even if he/she is not active on the site? That's not how GA works. You need to be active on the site in order to send data.

Comment: Is this the correct way to send the event data to google analytics?

Comment: @nyuen Sorry for the trouble but should I be using Google Tag Manager to achieve my requirement and also can I get the user data after User is not active

Comment: The syntax is correct, but I think your choice of event category, `pathName` should be something else more generic. Please review event tracking https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: You don't necessarily need GTM, but that depends on other things which would require further discussions. Again, you can't track data for an inactive user, but you should clarify what inactive means in this case.

Comment: I want to show the data as for abc.com/report.html .....X elementwas used so maybe abc.com/report.html should be [eventLabel] from Event fields but how will I get the X element in the context of Event fields?

Comment: @nyuen when User submits the page in question I can see User as active and I get the fields e.g. checkbox etc he has used.....User activity is submitting the page in question

Comment: I think GA will not be of help as requirement in question is to get the event history of a web page as a report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link gave all the answers to my questions on Google analytics Event Tracking 
  [Google Analytics Simplified](https://www.optimizesmart.com/event-tracking-guide-google-analytics-simplified-version/)
Sharing it for everyone who ever needs it.

Thanks anyway